# [JHipster new module][Error] needs a .yo-rc.json configuration file made by JHipster

Tags: javascript, yeoman, jhipster, yeoman-generator

I created a new JHipster module. And when I try to create a project using that module I'm getting this error.

```
needs a .yo-rc.json configuration file made by JHipster.
```

Comment: Maybe you could explain the purpose of your module.

Comment: If you want to create fresh project and use jhipster for some purpose then use the yeoman compose feature to compose jhipster. Take a look at the generator-jhipster-react project for example

Comment: @Deepu it looks as though the generator-jhipster-react project has the same problem as described above. After doing some digging, the root of the problem is with one of the method invocations in the constructor of "module.exports". The contents of "this.getAngularAppName()" method (within generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base.js) throws an error when "baseName" is null. But this will always be the case because no .yo-rc.json has been created yet. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the lifecycle here but if not, doesn't that mean composeWith will never work?

Answer (score 0):

JHipster modules are not supposed to create projects, they are supposed to modify or complement existing projects which of course come with their own  .yo-rc.json file.